# Is the zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by itself a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff

1. The zero vector ∈ W.
2. X + Y ∈ W for any X, Y ∈ W.
3. aX ∈ W for any X ∈ W and a ∈ R.

So, given W = { X : X = [x1...], x1 = 0, x2 = 0, ... xn = 0 } ∈ Rn

1. The zero vector ∈ W because each X in W is the zero vector by definition,
2. X + Y ∈ W because [0...] + [0...] = [0...]
3. aX ∈ W because a[0...] = [0...]

So if I understand this correctly, the zero vector is itself a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this correct?

In addition, can this be extended to say that for any W = { X : X = [$x_1$...] } ∈ $\mathbb{R}^n$, assuming W is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $x_i$ (an arbitrary component of W) can only be a constant if it is 0? (I.e., $x_i$ can't be 1 or 2, but can be 0)

Comment: The language is not quite correct, it's not the zero vector that is a subspace, but the set containing only the zero vector, $\{0\}$, that is a subspace. I'm not quite sure if I understand the last paragraph correctly, but for every subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$, the set of $i$-th components of the elements of $W$, $\{ x_i : x \in W\}$, is either $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, sorry - I literally just learned about subspaces today in class! That makes sense to me.

If I understand that last part correctly, xi can be any real number? I don't see how that's possible, because for example let's say you have W = { X : X = [1] }... if you say Y ∈ W (and therefore Y = [1]), then aY = a[1] ∉ W, so W is not a subspace of ℝ.

Comment: If you have one vector $x$ in $W$ with nonzero $i$-th component $x_i$, then since $c\cdot x \in W$ for all $c \in\mathbb{R}$, you have vectors with $i$-th component $c\cdot x_i$ in $W$, but for $x_i \neq 0$, $\{ c\cdot x_i : c \in\mathbb{R}\} = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The far more fun question: Now that you have seen that $\{0\}$ is a subspace, can you give a basis for it?

Comment: There isn't one! {0} is linearly dependent. :)

Comment: @alsuhr The basis is the empty set is it not?

Comment: @TylerHolden ditto

Answer (score 9):

Yes the set containing only the zero vector is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. It can arise in many ways by operations that always produce subspaces, like taking intersections of subspaces or the kernel of a linear map. It has dimension$~0$: one cannot find a linearly independent set containing any vectors at all, since $\{\vec0\}$ is already linearly dependent (taking $1$ times that vector is a nontrivial linear combination that gives the zero vector). The subspace is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^0$. Like any vector space of dimension$~k$, and hence like $\Bbb R^k$, it has a basis consisting of $k$ vectors; since $k=0$ such a basis is the empty set. Indeed, rather exceptionally, this is the *unique* basis for $\{\vec0\}$. That $\vec0$ is in the span of the empty set might seem strange, but the unique linear combination one can form of the empty set is the linear combination with no terms at all, and the value of such an empty sum (computed in a vector space) is by convention the zero vector.

In the comments to your question you chose the wrong one of the two available subsets $\emptyset$ and $\{0\}$ to be candidate for the basis; the latter has $1$ element which is too much for dimension$~0$, so naturally you find that it is linearly dependent.

Comment: I think your argument about $\{0\}$ being the wrong basis is kind of circular, as the dimension is defined (or, it's the most common definition I know) as the cardinality of any (and all) basis of the vector space. It's easier to see that $\{(0)\}$ is linearly dependent from the definition of linear dependace: $\alpha  \cdot 0=0 \not \equiv \alpha=0$.

Comment: Fair enough. I misunderstood what you meant. +1.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Took me sometime to get this.

1. Zero is a member of ${0}$.
2. ${0}$ is closed under addition. Let u and v be members of ${0}$. $u=v=0$ hence $u+v=0$.
3. ${0}$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed, $\{0\}$ is a subspace. In fact, for any vector space $V$ and any $x\in V$, we have that $\{x\}$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if $x$ is the zero vector of $V$, since any subspace of $V$ must contain the zero vector of $V$, and the subset of $V$ containing only the zero vector of $V$ is necessarily closed under addition and scalar multiplication (as you've shown).